# How can I convert my React component to be functional and use hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an existing component that I would like to convert to a hooks based component. I have a couple of IIFE inside my current component which I don't know how to convert. I want to use another hook inside this component which is why I want to convert this component. How should I go about making the conversion?

Here's my code:

```
class LineChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.chartRef = React.createRef();
    this.internalChart = null;
    this.state = {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          style: {
            fontFamily: '"Roboto", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;',
            width: '100%'
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: [],
          type: 'datetime',
          title: {
            text: "Time",
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
          },
          crosshair: {
            color: '#666666',
            width: 2,
          },
          labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
            }
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: this.props.metric,
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
          },
          labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              var outputVal = this.value;
              if(outputVal % 1) {
                outputVal = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2);
              } else {
                outputVal = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
              }
              return outputVal;
            }
          },
          startOnTick: false,
          endOnTick: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormatter: this.tooltipCallback
      },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
          maxHeight:100,
          margin: 6
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            },
            events: {
              legendItemClick: this.legendCallback
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  afterChartCreated = (chart) => {
    this.internalChart = chart;
  }


  legendCallback = (function(self) {
    return function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if(!this.visible) { //selected/enabled
        self.props.onEnableLegend({
          categoryId: self.props.categoryId,
          panelId: self.props.panelId,
          payload: event.target.name
        });
      } else { //deselected/disabled
        self.props.onDisableLegend({
          categoryId: self.props.categoryId,
          panelId: self.props.panelId,
          payload: event.target.name
        });
      }
    }
  })(this);

  tooltipCallback = (function(self) {
    return function() {
      var value = this.y;
      if (value % 1) {
        value = Highcharts.numberFormat(value, 2);
      } else {
        value = Highcharts.numberFormat(value, 0);
      }
      var symbol = '';
      
      switch ( this.series.symbol ) {
          case 'circle':
              symbol = '●';
              break;
          case 'diamond':
              symbol = '♦';
              break;
          case 'square':
              symbol = '■';
              break;
          case 'triangle':
              symbol = '▲';
              break;
          case 'triangle-down':
              symbol = '▼';
              break;
      }

      const unitStr = self.props.metricUnit ? " (" + self.props.metricUnit + ")" : "";
      return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + symbol + '</span>' + ' ' + this.series.name + ': ' + value + unitStr +  '<br/>';
    }
  })(this);
  
  render() {
    if(this.props.data === undefined || Object.keys(this.props.data).length === 0 || this.props.data.categories.length === 0) {
      return(<div style={{position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%', transform: 'translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)'}}>No data available</div>);
    } else {
      const series = this.props.data['series'];
      var newSeries = series.map(element => {
        return {
          ...element,
          visible: false
        }
      });
      newSeries.forEach(element => {
        if(!this.props.enabledLegends.includes(element['name'])) {
          element['visible'] = false;
        } else {
          element['visible'] = true;
        }
      });
      const categories = this.props.data['categories'];
      const chartOptions = {...this.state.chartOptions};
      const unitStr = (this.props.metricUnit !== undefined && this.props.metricUnit !== null) ? " (" + this.props.metricUnit + ")" : "";
      chartOptions['yAxis']['title']['text'] = this.props.metric + unitStr;
      chartOptions['series'] = newSeries;
      chartOptions['xAxis']['categories'] = categories;
      if(this.props.min !== null && !isNaN(this.props.min)) {
        // console.log("Chart min value: " + this.props.min);
        chartOptions['yAxis']['min'] = this.props.min;
      }
      if(this.props.zmax !== null && !isNaN(this.props.max)) {
        chartOptions['yAxis']['max'] = this.props.max;
      }
      // console.log(chartOptions);
      return (
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions}
        ref={this.chartRef}
        callback={this.afterChartCreated}/>
      );
    }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LineChart);
```

Comment: Currently your component has a gigantic state object in `chartOptions`. If you need that much state, it might be wiser to keep your component a class and find another solution. But if you want/need to use functional component, I would consider moving the Highchart options to a function, e.g. `getChartOptions`. You probably also would need the `useState` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook, which adds state-like functionality in React functional components.

Comment: What about the IIFE function? If you see, I am using the ```legendCallBack``` and ```tooltipCallback``` functions here. How do I convert those?